# IOS DBRestClient: Where to put DBREstClient

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

Okay. So I have 3 .h and .m files, (2 controllers and 1 delegate) and I am somewhat new to Objective C so the instructions in dropbox have been confusing to say the least. I am coming from a Javascript background and understand the logic, but not what code to use. I tried putting the code in each combination of .h and .m files. (The controller .h and .m file then the .h and .m file for the delegate then the .h and .m file for the other controller deleting the code from the previous file before trying it on another set of files)

I am deeply confused and

.h file

```
@interface <controller/delegate> : NSObject {
     DBRestClient *restClient;
}
```

.m file

```
- (DBRestClient*)restClient {
    if (restClient == nil) {
        restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}
```

I can only run this code in one of the classes. A controller, but I get this error:

Incompatible pointer types assigning to id

How would I fix this and is it even in the right place?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do with your restClient method? I'm guessing that your [DBSession sharedSession] type is incompatible with the initWithSession call.

Comment: I'm using the restClient method to connect with dropbox so that I may sync/download files. The error I keep getting is incompatibility with the class in the line `restClient.delegate = self;` It happens with every class and I don't know if I'm supposed to declare a new class or something.

Comment: That means in the .h file, in the interface declaration, you'd have to declare that your class is a delegate of the class. e.g. @interface MyClass : NSObject <RestClientDelegate>

Comment: I did that but still get incompatible pointer types or Assigning to 'id<DbRestClient Delegate>' from incompatible type 'myViewController*'

Comment: Can you update your code with that declaration in your .h file?

Comment: `@protocol DBRestClientDelegate;

@interface <controller> : NSObject
{
   id<DBRestClientDelegate> delegate;
    DBRestClient *restClient;
}

@property (assign) id <DBRestClientDelegate> delegate;
`

Answer (score -2):

I am posting the link of dropbox Tutorial, in which you will find dropbox api and one tutorial project.It is very nicely described there.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

Below is documentation link, you just read it once.You will get clear idea.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Ya, I already read it. That's why I'm here asking about it. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Still unanswered can someone please reply.

Comment: hey bro...I will post whole code ..don't worry...let me finsih my stuff first......!!!!

Comment: Oh sorry. Will wait patiently.

Comment: Hi , sorry for late reply...now tell me what's your problem??